# How to deploy .Net Core WebAPI and React JS application to single Docker container

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, .net-core

> We are developing an application where UI is developed using ReactJS
>   and APIs are developed on .Net Core framework. ReactJS application
>   will be deployed on Nginx.  WebAPIs will also use NGinx for reverse
>   proxy.
>
> I am trying to write a script for generating docker container for the
>   entire application.
>
> Docker recommends to use separate container in such situations and use
>   docker compose for handling dependencies between the containers. But
>   our application have a reporting feature in which reports generated by
>   APIs are stored on virtual directory accessible by Web application.
>   For this reason we were thinking to have single container for whole
>   application.
>
> Will having a single container cause any issue? Can we run Nginx and
>   Kestrel in one docker container using shell command file?

Answer (score 1):

You should listen to Docker's recommendation on this issue. I was of the exact same mentality for an API/Angular app. I would look into using the volumes declaration in docker-compose to create symlinks in each container that map to the same directory on the host machine. This was my solution to deal with logs from microservices